# Chapter Dependency Diagram in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, chapters

Please look at the complex chapter dependency diagram **EXAMPLE** in the given image. It explains how each chapter is dependent on the previous one. I am sure diagrams of this type can be done (hard coded, I would say) in `Tikz`. **I DON'T NEED THE HELP TO IMPLEMENT IT IN TIKZ.** I was looking for more of a package kind of out-of-the-box solution, where you can mention the dependencies and the package will automatically generate the diagram for you. Is there any solution as such. I searched in TeX.SX for similar questions and found that in all cases, `TikZ` is the recommended option. This feature or package if implemented will be useful for people like me as we are required to include a chapter reading order or dependency diagram.

[image]

UPDATE: The ideal solution for the above diagram should be something like

```
\chapter{Chapter 1}
bla bla bla

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\RequiredDependency{chapter1_label}

\chapter{Chapter 3}

\chapter{Chapter 4}
\RequiredDependency{chapter1_label}
\RecommendedDependency{chapter2_label,chapter3_label}
```

and so on. Once I do this, the above diagram should be generated.

Comment: what happens if seventh depends on the first chapter? drawn over the fifth? Object avoidance in TikZ is not feasible, if not impossible.

Comment: isn't it possible in tikz that one can manually pick the co-ordinates in the diagrams and connect the lines such that it goes round the object, a kind of poly path thing?

Comment: But that wouldn't be out-of-the-box solution if your contribution is involved right? We will be back at the image you have given. Or am I not reading the question correctly?

Comment: Please read the update at the end of the question

Comment: May be [prerequisite chart](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/prerequisite-chart/)example is usefull for you. [`prerex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/prerex)package is in CTAN.

Comment: @Ignasi Can you add that as an answer, I just saw it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`prerex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/prerex) package is intended to draw prerequisite charts like [these ones](http://www.cs.queensu.ca/students/undergraduate/prerequisites/) It's based on `TikZ` and its `README` file starts with:

> prerex, version 6.5.3: Macros for prerequisite charts, with associated
>   editor and viewer applications.
>
> This package consists of
>
> `prerex.sty`: 
>       a LaTeX package for producing charts of course nodes
>       linked by arrows representing pre- and co-requisites,
>
> `prerex`:
>       an interactive program for creating and editing chart
>       descriptions, and
>
> `vprerex`: ("visual prerex") a GUI and previewer for prerex.

I've never used before, but (without using its interactive program) I wrote next code to produce something similar to your example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{noheadfoot, vmargin=1.0in, hmargin=0.5in}
\usepackage{prerex}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{diagheight}{50}


\begin{chart}%\grid
\reqhalfcourse 45,45:{}{Chapter 1}{}
\reqhalfcourse 35,36:{}{Chapter 2}{}
\reqhalfcourse 55,36:{}{Chapter 3}{}
\reqhalfcourse 35,27:{}{Chapter 4}{}
\reqhalfcourse 55,27:{}{Chapter 5}{}
\reqhalfcourse 68,27:{}{Chapter 6}{}
\reqhalfcourse 68,18:{}{Chapter 7}{}
\reqhalfcourse 45,9:{}{Chapter 8}{}

\prereq 45,45,35,36:
\prereq 68,27,68,18:

\prereqc 45,45,35,27;-30:
\prereqc 45,45,55,27;-30:
\prereqc 35,27,45,9;0:
\prereqc 68,18,45,9;0:
\prereqc 68,27,45,9;0:

\coreq 55,27,68,27:
\coreq 35,36,35,27: 
\coreq 35,36,55,27: 
\coreq 55,36,55,27: 
\coreq 55,36,35,27: 

\begin{pgfonlayer}{courses}
\draw[dashed] ([shift={(-1mm,-1mm)}]x55y27.south west) rectangle ([shift={(1mm,1mm)}]x68y27.north east);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{chart}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to change the color inside the boxes from yellow to something else?

Comment: @MrPajeet    According to the [manual](https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/graphics/prerex/doc/prerex.pdf) all command have a version without default color. As exaemple: `\reqhalfcoursec 45,45:{}{Chapter 1}{}{red}` where the last argument is the background color.

Comment: It didn't work, this did though: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/652910/87628

Answer (score 9):

The CVS version of TikZ contains a graph drawing library that automatically lays out the components of a graph.

Here's what it comes up with automatically:

[image]

```
\tikz \graph [layered layout]
{
C1 -> {C2, C4, C5},
C2 ->[densely dashed] {C4, C5},
C3 ->[densely dashed] {C4, C5},
C5 -> {C7, C8},
C4 -> C8,
C7 -> C8
};
```

So you'll have to do quite a bit of nudging to get it to look decent. I think this is a case where a manual approach works better: the network isn't really complicated enough to make an automated approach necessary, and it's much easier to get something pleasing to human eyes if the layout is done by a human.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}


\begin{document}

\tikz \graph [layered layout]
{
C1 -> {C2, C4, C5},
C2 ->[densely dashed] {C4, C5},
C3 ->[densely dashed] {C4, C5},
C5 -> {C7, C8},
C4 -> C8,
C7 -> C8
};

\end{document}
```