# How to outline a curriculum/course tree?

Tags: tikz-pgf

For the desired output curriculum/course tree below, what is the best approach to reproduce the same conceivable (i.e. to recognize the course prerequisites) output using latex without the need to draw it myself **manually**?

In other words, is it possible to find a way to define my input to be: (a) the courses names, (b) their prerequisites, and (c) their parent level, while latex optimizes the courses/nodes placement and connects each course with its prerequisites?

[image]

Comment: something like this:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/203692/15036 ?

Comment: I don't know, but do you think that adding a few `right of` and `below` of keys is really more effort than trying to find the right graph drawing algorithm, and to nudge the boxes if you don't like the result?

Comment: @marmot For this MWE, you are right. However, for more than 60 courses in 5 levels with different dependencies, I need to find a more robust solution if possible. If the robust solution is not easy to find nor doable, the manual approach is OK for me.

Comment: Does it helps? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141244/1952

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but to tell you how much effort it would be to draw this one by hand. I hope to see another, more automatic answer and thus learn something new.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[course/.style={draw,minimum width=2cm,minimum
height=8mm,node contents={Course #1},name=n#1},
font=\sffamily,node distance=2cm and 1cm]
\node[course=1];
\node[right=of n1,course=2];
\node[right=of n2,course=3];
\node[below=of n1,course=5];
\node[right=of n5,course=6];
\node[right=1.8cm of n6,course=4];
%
\node[below=of n5,course=9];
\node[right=2.3cm of n9,course=7];
\node[right=of n7,course=8];
\node[below right=2cm and -0.5cm of n9,course=10];
\node[right=1.8cm of n10,course=11];
\node[right=of n11,course=12];
%
\begin{scope}[thick]
\draw (n1) -- (n5) coordinate[midway] (aux1)
(n6.140) |- (aux1) (n2) -- (n6) 
(n6.-40) coordinate(aux2) -- (n7.north -| aux2)
(n3.-155) coordinate(aux3) -- (n7.north -| aux3)
(n9.-35) coordinate(aux4) -- (n10.north -| aux4)
(n12.40) |- (n4)
(n7.south) -- ++ (0,-0.4) coordinate(aux5) -| (n10)
(aux5) -| (n12);
%
\node[fit=(n1) (n4),inner xsep=8mm,inner ysep=2mm] (fit1){};
\draw ([xshift=2mm]fit1.south west) -| (fit1.north west)
node[pos=0.75,left=3mm,font=\sffamily\bfseries]{Level 1} -- ++(2mm,0);
%
\node[fit=(n9) (n12),inner xsep=8mm,inner ysep=2mm] (fit2){};
\draw ([xshift=2mm]fit2.south west) -| (fit2.north west)
node[pos=0.75,left=3mm,font=\sffamily\bfseries]{Level 2} -- ++(2mm,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]