# Change color in Prerex, chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-styles, charts

How do I change the color from Yellow to say, gray. Also I don't like the rounded boxes, and the thick boundary. The package documentation doesn't clearly say what I must do either.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{prerex}

\begin{document}
\begin{chart}%\grid
            \reqhalfcourse 30,55:{}{Foundations\\of Physics}{}{Melon}
            \reqhalfcourse 10,45:{}{Functional\\Analysis}{}
            \reqhalfcourse -12,30:{}{Sheaf\\Theory}{}
            \reqhalfcourse -5,05:{}{Microlocal\\Sheaves}{}
            \reqhalfcourse 13,22:{}{Complex\\Analysis}{}
            \reqhalfcourse 20,30:{}{Operator\\Algebras}{}
            \reqhalfcourse 5,15:{}{Microlocal\\Analysis}{}
            \reqhalfcourse 40,40:{}{Operational\\Theories}{}
            \reqhalfcourse 20,00:{}{AQFT}{}
            \reqhalfcourse 40,27:{}{Quantum\\Foundations}{}
            \reqhalfcourse 58,27:{}{Evolution}{}
            \reqhalfcourse 58,18:{}{Thermodynamics}{}
            \reqhalfcourse 20,-20:{}{Quantum\\Gravity}{}
            
            \prereq 5,15,20,00:
            \prereq 10,45,20,30:
            \prereq 10,45,5,15:
            \prereqc 13,22,20,00:
            \prereqc -12,30,-5,05:
            \prereq -5,05,20,00:
            \prereq 58,18,58,27:
            \prereq 20,30,20,00: 
            \prereqc 20,00,20,-20;0:
            \prereqc 58,18,20,-20;0:
            \prereqc 58,27,20,-20;0:
            
            \coreq 13,22,40,40:
            \coreq 30,55,58,18:
            \coreq 20,30,40,27: 
            \coreq 30,55,20,00:
            \coreq 30,55,40,27:
            \coreq 40,27,20,00:
            \coreq 40,27,58,27:
            
            
            \coreq 40,40,40,27: 
            \coreq 40,40,20,00: 
            
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{courses}
                \draw[dashed] ([shift={(-2mm,-1mm)}]x40y27.south west) rectangle ([shift={(1mm,2mm)}]x58y27.north east);
            \end{pgfonlayer}
        \end{chart}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `prerex` uses different approaches to set the default appearance of the nodes. Some values are stored in variables that you cound redefine (such as `\background` for the background color which is set to `yellow!15` by default, or different line widths), but other things, such as the border radius, are more or less hard coded.

The most straight-forward and yet highly customizable approach would be to place the nodes inside the `chart` environment inside a `scope` and redefine the appearance of the nodes using regular Ti*k*Z style options like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{prerex}

\begin{document}

\begin{chart}%\grid
    \begin{scope}[every rectangle node/.style={
        sharp corners,
        line width=0.6pt,
        fill=gray!15
    }]
        \reqhalfcourse 30,55:{}{Foundations\\of Physics}{}{Melon}
        \reqhalfcourse 10,45:{}{Functional\\Analysis}{}
        \reqhalfcourse -12,30:{}{Sheaf\\Theory}{}
        \reqhalfcourse -5,05:{}{Microlocal\\Sheaves}{}
        \reqhalfcourse 13,22:{}{Complex\\Analysis}{}
        \reqhalfcourse 20,30:{}{Operator\\Algebras}{}
        \reqhalfcourse 5,15:{}{Microlocal\\Analysis}{}
        \reqhalfcourse 40,40:{}{Operational\\Theories}{}
        \reqhalfcourse 20,00:{}{AQFT}{}
        \reqhalfcourse 40,27:{}{Quantum\\Foundations}{}
        \reqhalfcourse 58,27:{}{Evolution}{}
        \reqhalfcourse 58,18:{}{Thermodynamics}{}
        \reqhalfcourse 20,-20:{}{Quantum\\Gravity}{}
    \end{scope}
    
    \prereq 5,15,20,00:
    \prereq 10,45,20,30:
    \prereq 10,45,5,15:
    \prereqc 13,22,20,00:
    \prereqc -12,30,-5,05:
    \prereq -5,05,20,00:
    \prereq 58,18,58,27:
    \prereq 20,30,20,00: 
    \prereqc 20,00,20,-20;0:
    \prereqc 58,18,20,-20;0:
    \prereqc 58,27,20,-20;0:
    
    \coreq 13,22,40,40:
    \coreq 30,55,58,18:
    \coreq 20,30,40,27: 
    \coreq 30,55,20,00:
    \coreq 30,55,40,27:
    \coreq 40,27,20,00:
    \coreq 40,27,58,27:
    
    
    \coreq 40,40,40,27: 
    \coreq 40,40,20,00: 
    
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{courses}
        \draw[dashed] ([shift={(-2mm,-1mm)}]x40y27.south west) rectangle ([shift={(1mm,2mm)}]x58y27.north east);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{chart}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Damn! This is exactly like I wanted. Thanks a lot!